# Where is the REDHAWK IDE generated port type frontend::OutDigitalScanningTunerPort defined?

Tags: c++, redhawksdr

I have a REDHAWK component written in Python but with the new logic I have added it is using up too much CPU.  I want to convert it to c++.  I copied the properties from the python component .prf file to the new c++ component and generated.  Although everything was fine with the generated Python code, I get the following error when trying to build the generated c++ code with no changes:

```
MinionControllerCpp_base.h:115:9: error: 'OutDigitalScanningTunerPort' in namespace 'frontend' does not name a type
         frontend::OutDigitalScanningTunerPort *digitalScanningTuner_out;
```

I searched in the REDHAWK include directory with no luck.  I am using REDHAWK 2.2.3.  Since the code was generated by the REDHAWK IDE, it seems the type should be defined somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in 2.2.3 where the output digital scanning port implementation is missing in C++. This bug will be fixed in the 2.2.6 release

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. When making statements like these, could you provide a source with the information? In this case a link to the issue tracker or something similar would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Output ports cannot be scanning; this is a feature in some receivers to allow a scan pattern across wider bandwidths than can be covered by the instantaneous bandwidth of the receiver. If you want a digital scanner input to receive, use `frontend::InDigitalScanningTunerPort`. If you're trying to transmit, use `frontend::OutDigitalTunerPort` instead.

Comment: The error is happening on the controller side.  I am converting the controlling component to python, not the tuner device that is being controlled.

Comment: I tried to edit my comment but there is a 5 minute window.  Here is the code from the .scd.xml file:        <uses repid="IDL:FRONTEND/DigitalScanningTuner:1.0" usesname="digitalScanningTuner_out">
        <porttype type="control"/>
      </uses>

Comment: @mybodycravesbutterygoodness Could you clarify whether you are attempting to control a transmitter or receiver? If you could provide a diagram of the components you are using, that would be even better.

Comment: I am using it as a receiver but it looks like user13197868 has the answer.